# Javamail: Email leaves successfully from program but is not delivered Windows Server 2012 r2

Tags: email, windows-server-2012-r2, email-server

I am severely stuck on this problem.

My program successfully delivers emails from my Windows 10 PC and Windows Server 2012 R2 Essential but sending it through any other **Windows Server 2012 versions** shows as successfully sent but the email is not delivered.

Have tried all combinations of **SSL/TLS/No authentication** as well as all ports **465/587/26.**

This is the code that i'm using

```
    String port = "26";
    // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
    String to = "*****@gmail.com";

    // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
    String host = "mail.*****.com.pk";
    String username = "sales@*****.com.pk";//change accordingly
    String password = "*****";//change accordingly

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    // SSL Factory
    // props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
    //           "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");

    System.out.println("TLS Settings False");
    System.out.println("Sending with port: " + port);

    // Get the Session object.
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

    try {
        // Create a default MimeMessage object.
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

        // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));

        // Set To: header field of the header.
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(to));

        // Set Subject: header field
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject from ******.com.pk");

        // Now set the actual message
        message.setText("Hello, this is sample for to check send " +
                "email using JavaMailAPI on personal workstation ");

        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

I have also tried using Jodd Mail Library which replicates the same situation which gives me reason to believe the OS is the issue here

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would be using port 465 (implicit TLS) or 587 (explicit TLS/“STARTTLS” or, if you have to, unencrypted submission). Port 25 (not 26) should be used for traffic between mail servers.

The important question when troubleshooting mail that’s accepted by your MTA but not delivered to the recipient, is how the delivery rate looks for other mail sent from the same server, and especially to the same domain that apparently discards mail from your program.

There are a number of things you can do to improve deliverability, starting with a secure mail server configuration (I.e. not being the source of spam), followed by correctly applied SPF, DKIM, and DMARC records/headers in your DNS+MTA.

Comment: Thank you for the response. As I mentioned in my question emails from my own personal computer running Windows 10 are all delivered 100%. No domain emails from my server are being delivered. Although emails sent through my gmail account using my program are delivered successfully.

Comment: Well, if it works when you send through gmail, your program works, and most recipients trust Google as a sender. I'm assuming you're not a large company. Is your server used for all your organization's mail needs, and do you experience problems with sending other kinds of mail through it?

Comment: No, outlook works fine. I'm assuming that's what you meant.

Comment: What do your mail server logs say about the messages you try to send using your program? Does the recipient server accept them at all? Try sending a mail to a spamminess tester like https://www.mail-tester.com and see what advice you get.

Comment: I do not know how to check what mail server log says, can you guide me? The library logs that my application outputs says successfully sent. mail-tester.com did not receive my email either.

Comment: What mail server software do you run?